# VM Player 12.5.7 does not accept gcc 7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware, gcc, vmware-player

Hello my dear Linux users,

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and I have `gcc-7` installed using the [Toolchain test builds](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test).

When I start `VM Player 12.5.7 build-5813279` it is asking for `gcc 7.2`. I point it to `/usr/bin/gcc-7` but it says that this gcc version is not compatible.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

[image]

Comment: Please run `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` and paste into your question

Comment: Are linux headers files installed if not install: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I'm currently in aptitude. There seem to be several unmet dependies:
binutils >=2.26.1, cpp-7 =7.2.0, libisl15 >=0.15, lipmc3, lipmfr4 >=3.1.3 ...The problem is that aptitude keeps saying that these dependencies are unavailable. I have been trying to add them to the install list in aptitude.

Comment: Yes, header files are installed: linux-headers-4.13.4-041304-lowlatency

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: 0 updated, 0 installed, 0 ...

Comment: Can you reinstall gcc again, `sudo apt-get install  --reinstall gcc`

Comment: Reinstalled.  gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66405/discussion-between-george-and-johann-ka).

Answer (score 4):

I solved via the  : 

`` cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
cd vmnet-only
make
cd ..
tar -xf vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only
make
cd ..
cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko
cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko
depmod -a
/etc/init.d/vmware restart ``

One may need to use `sudo` before each command above.

While running make during the above command execution, if there is an error, search the error in vmware community for a patch. For example i solved one issue using the following patch :

`diff -Naur vmnet-only.orig/bridge.c vmnet-only/bridge.c
--- vmnet-only/bridge.c 2017-06-26 22:08:39.148034785 +1000
+++ vmnet-only/bridge.c 2017-07-16 11:37:01.325802125 +1000
@@ -636,7 +636,7 @@
         unsigned long flags;
         int i;
-        atomic_inc(&clone->users);
+        clone = skb_get(clone);
         clone->dev = dev;
         clone->protocol = eth_type_trans(clone, dev);`

If you have the `version.h` file missing in your vmware log, try below code:

`cd /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include/linux/
ln -s /usr/include/linux/version.h version.h`

Note: I got all the above information from the Internet
Now i can launch VMWare player

Comment: This also works for any of the version mismatch of vmmon/vmnet.ko and other related issues. I recompiled and copied manually as above. It worked  in my case as well. This is for the current latest VMware Player v14.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VMWARE 12.5.8 with GCC 7.2.0 . I followed the steps mentioned by sandoche balakrichenan and I face some issues while making the vmmon-only folder. I had to do a few additional steps to get vmware working.

Here are my steps :

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
cd vmnet-only
make
cd ..
tar -xf vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only
make
```

[faced some issues and couldn't create the vmmon.o file. RFollowed steps from here -> [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/installing-vmware-workstation-modules-fail-to-build-4175617760/) 
Copied these from this GITHUB -> [here](https://github.com/pavlinux/vmware-modules) into the /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source folder]

```
cd ..
```

[Create the misc folder if necessary]

```
cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko
cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko
depmod -a
/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In my experience with this, you should click the "OK" button on the pop up. The VMware Kernel Module Updater should come up again. Just point it to your gcc-7 again. It should compile. If that still fails you will need to have to install gcc-7.2. This will be from the Toolchain test builds.
Use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update -y && \
sudo apt-get upgrade -y && \
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
sudo apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y && \
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y && \
sudo apt-get update -y && \
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7 -y && \
```

This part must be done:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 && \
```

Now:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

NOTE:

This works on Debian as well but instead of adding the Ubuntu repo you can add:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

to the end of:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now try the VMware Kernel Module Updater again. You may just see gcc-7 only. Just point there; it will be gcc-7.2. If the incompatible warning comes up, do as I stated above.

Hope this helps,

Comment: gcc-7.2.0 is installed on my system. Repeatedly trying to make VM Player pick gcc-7.2.0 does not work.

Comment: Did you follow my guide? This was what I had to do every time I updated the kernel.

Comment: @johann_ka Please run `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` and paste into your question

Comment: Since you have gcc-7 installed using the Toolchain test builds, I would give the gcc-7.2 a try from repository ppa:jonathonf.

Comment: @George - the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` is `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc` ..I have been trying to get this back (registering gcc) but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: My gcc-7 in installed at `/usr/bin/gcc-7` according to `which gcc-7`.

Comment: @Dave - this suggestion didn't work. Maybe because of the prior Toolchain install.

Comment: Please check out my updated answer.