# VMware player fails to compile modules on Ubuntu 18.04- GCC error?

Tags: kernel, vmware

When I start VMware Player I get the dialog box below. This is my current GCC version, but gcc-6 and gcc-5 are also installed.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 april  6 20:04 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-7
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 april 15 06:52 /usr/bin/gcc-7 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7
```

Apt outputs:

```
$ apt list gcc
Listing... Done
gcc/bionic,now 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
$ apt list linux-headers-generic
Listing... Done
linux-headers-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0.32.34 amd64 [installed]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

[image: Screenshot of error showing GNU C Compiler version 7.3.0 was not found]

None of the GCCs work when specifying the path in the dialog, I get this message:

[image: A compatible version of gcc was not found]

I'm using the current version of VMware player from the website, the runnable installer file: `VMware-Player-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle`.

What could possibly be going wrong here? There are other questions like this one, but for earlier versions, and the solutions don't work for me (e.g. [VM Player 12.5.7 does not accept gcc 7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959113/vm-player-12-5-7-does-not-accept-gcc-7-2-on-ubuntu-14-04) )

Comment: The only path that seems to work is the default system version so you will have to use that, had the same problem

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen that is actually a good enough answer to my question:) I've tried with /usr/bin/gcc and it doesn't work here, but this indicates that there's a problem in my environment. I hope people don't mind if I change the question to ask for a solution instead of whether it works, since it's already confirmed that it works for someone in a comment.

Comment: Updates to your question is aloud

Answer (score 0):

The new version VMware-Player-14.1.3-9474260.x86_64.bundle solves the issue for me. After installation, there is no prompt for module compilation or GCC.